# Issue on ocilib error handling, how to correctly catch logs errors with ocilib?

Tags: c++, ocilib

I have a problem with error handling on ocilib.

I am currently using the OCILIB provides two mechanisms for error handling:

- Global error handling through callbacks.
- Contextual thread error handling

How I am initializing :

```
if (!isInit && !OCI_Initialize(&OracleManager::errorHandler, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT | OCI_ENV_CONTEXT))
    throw ibs::exceptions::trace::db(61400, mManager.getMessage(61400));
```

My error handling callback :

```
static void errorHandler(OCI_Error *error)
{
    LOG_(ibs::io::log::IN_CONSOLE, plog::debug) << OCI_GetSql(OCI_ErrorGetStatement(error));
    LOG_(ibs::io::log::IN_FILE, plog::debug) << OCI_GetSql(OCI_ErrorGetStatement(error));
    throw ibs::exceptions::trace::db(61403, "code: " + std::to_string(OCI_ErrorGetOCICode(error)) + ", " + OCI_ErrorGetString(error));
}
```

Contextual thread error handling :

```
if (!OCI_ExecuteStmt(mSt, query.c_str()))
{
    OCI_Error   *err = OCI_GetLastError();

    if (err == nullptr || OCI_ErrorGetOCICode(err) == 0)
    {        
        LOG_(ibs::io::log::IN_CONSOLE, plog::debug) << query;
        LOG_(ibs::io::log::IN_FILE, plog::debug) << query;
        throw ibs::exceptions::trace::db(61407, mManager.getMessage(61407));
    }
    errorHandler(err);
}
```

My problem is :

On my first insertion (on database) error : Ocilib call my callback with the correct error description.

On my second (and more) insertion error : Ocilib does not call my callback BUT OCI_ExecuteStmt() return me "false" and my data is not inserted into the database.

The fact that an error is detected is correct, it must be. But, for my second (and more) error, I have no information's about my error.

For traceability purpose, I need to known : Why my data are rejected ?

My problem is that I have this information only for the first error.

And even for the contextual thread error handling, the OCI_GetLastError() function return me a null pointer even if the data was rejected and OCI_ExecuteStmt() return me "false".

For example :

1. I am inserting incorrect data with ocilib.
2. Ocilib tell me that the data is incorrect and why (through the callback).
3. I am inserting the same incorrect data with ocilib.
4. Ocilib tell me that there is something wrong without calling the callback and ocilib does not tell me why (this is the problem).
5. I am inserting another incorrect data with ocilib.
6. Ocilib tell me that there is something wrong without calling the callback and ocilib does not tell me why.

Maybe I am doing something wrong on how I handle errors. Help would be appreciated.

Using 4.6.2 ocilib version on a C++11 application.

Answer (score 0):

Can you open an issue on ocilib GitHub repo with a sample code 
 reproducting the issue?

Btw, as you're coding in C++, why not using Ocilib C++ API?